# How to select an integer from an input of multiple integers?

Tags: java

Suppose a user inputs a list of multiple integers 0 6 2 3 9 5

How do I select, for example the first integer, 0?
And how do I select, for example the third integer, 2?

Comment: You may want to look into how to read from stdin and then Arrays. `allIntegers = stdin.nextInt();` does not do what you expect it to do.

Comment: Okay, I have only programmed for 3 hours in my whole life so excuse me for the dumb questions. My problem is that I have a user input of 6 integers and I need to be able to select each of them separately and assign each of them to a different variable but I don't know how to do that. :(

Answer (score 2):

In the Java language, you have arrays which can hold many objects inside of one variable. They're useful for storing many users, or holding different names.

To **create** an array, you'll write like you are making a new object, but put '[' and ']' after it. Then put the number of objects you want to store inside. For example, `new Leg[4]`.

We count from 0 in arrays, so the fifth object, would be at position 4 in the array.

To **get** or **write** to an array, refer to the array and in brackets, write the position. Such as, `myLegs[2]` would return the third `Leg`.

For this case, you will need to have an array of integers (`int`).

```
int[] integers = new int[6]; // Creates an array of 6 integers.
// Note, an integer is the same as int.

integers[0] = stdin.nextInt(); // Let's assume the user typed 0.
integers[1] = stdin.nextInt(); //                             6
integers[2] = stdin.nextInt(); //                             2
integers[3] = stdin.nextInt(); //                             3
integers[4] = stdin.nextInt(); //                             9
integers[5] = stdin.nextInt(); //                             5

System.out.println(integers[0]); // The first integer. This would print "0".
System.out.println(integers[4]); // The fifth integer. This would print "9".
```

Comment: You may want to add a bit about how this works to beef your answer up a bit...

Answer (score 0):

Well, if they put in a list of integers in that format, you can break them into tokens with this:

```
String input = "0 6 2 3 9 5";
String[] tokens = input.split(" ");
int[] inputNumbers = new int[tokens.length];
for(int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
    inputNumbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(tokens[i]);
}
```

This'll give you an int array that you can reference to get the numbers.

For the 2nd entry:

```
int secondEntry = inputNumbers[1];
```